# React native navigator animation not translating full device width

Tags: animation, react-native

I have a React Native app running on Android with a Navigator component. I'm finding that when transitioning between scenes that the animation is only translating about 1/3 of the device width. I have seen that within the NavigatorSceneConfigs https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.15.0/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js that the library is using the Dimensions of the device which is reporting 411.42857.... I'm running this on a Nexus 6 which is reporting a PixelRatio of 3.5. These numbers seem correct since multiplying these gives the devices resolution of 1440.

I have checked that the navigator and scene are filling the full device width. I would have expected it to translate the full width of the device. What have I missed configured or how have I missed understood what to expect from the Navigator animations?

```
class Root extends Component{
  render() {
     const routes = []
     routes.push({
        title: 'first'
     })
     routes.push({
        title: 'second'
     })
     return (
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: "transparent"}}>
           <Navigator style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
                      initialRouteStack={routes}
                      sceneStyle={{flex:1}}
                      renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
              <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
                 <Text>{route.title}{Dimensions.get('window').width} {PixelRatio.get()}</Text>
              </View>
           }
           />
        </View>
     );
  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Seed', () => Root);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug on ReactNative 0.14 and 0.15. I have justed test 0.16 and it is fixed.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4221